# Shortcut to Preferences

Tags: shortcut-keys, 16.10, preferences

On Macs, there's a nice command + , to open prefs in any app. For example, in Firefox right now, preferences is in the Edit menu (WTF, but that's a different bug), and no shortcut keys to press it.

How does one universally set a shortcut to open preferences?

P.S. / Extra Credit: Is there a way and a place to productively lodge a complaint about preferences being in the Edit menu that might help it get changed?

Comment: You can use Help > Submit Feedback to complain about where the preferences item is, but personally I think it's in a logical place. Edit preferences makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single shortcut for that. But on Ubuntu with Unity desktop, you have an alternative - Unity Hud.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> shows search menu, where you can search for specific menu entries you want ( from File, Edit, View, and others). Just search for Preferences, and you'll be presented with an option for that (if the app itself has Preferences menu; if developers didn't put it there, well . . .there's not much you can do about that)

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to assign shortcut to that Unity Hud link to preferences?

Comment: @TomMercer technically, no. You can "simulate it" , with `xdotool`, which  can automate keypresses. So lets say you bind specific `xdotool` command to a shortcut ; pressing it will basically press alt and type out "preferences". Same thing as done by hand, except automatic. If you want , I can edit that into my answer later